# Switch statement with two arguments

Tags: c, switch-statement

I have a question related to switch statement with 2 arguments. I do not understand which value to look for. I've read somewhere that comma(,) is equal to AND,but that is not helping me much since when debugging it goes to case 1,case 1,and then default,so I  really don't get it.

Any help would be appreaciated,Thanks!

````
#define ADD(x, y) x+y
#define MUL(x, y) x*y
void main() {
    int arr[6] = { 012, -2, 7 - 011, 0x1F, 3 }, res = 0;
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int), i, j;
    for (i = -1, j = n; i <= n / 2;) {
        switch (--j, ++i) {
        case 0: res += MUL(arr[i], arr[j]);
        case 1: res += ADD(arr[i], arr[j]); break;
        case 4: res += MUL(ADD(arr[i], arr[j]), ADD(arr[i + 1], res));
        default: res++; break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", res);
} ```
````

Comment: you (probably) need a `break` in `case 0:` and `case 4:` ... also add parenthesis (for each parameter and for the whole thing) in the defines: `#define ADD(x, y) ((x)+(y))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operator comma is not equal to  AND. Operator comma evaluates operands from left to right, and returns the last result. Thus,

```
switch (--j, ++i) {
```

i = 0;
it goes to the case 0, you don`t have break statement so you go to the case 1

Comment: I understand now,i've forgot about that it will go on if break is not there. Thanks!